# How to unit test if Vuex action has been dispatched in VueJS

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, vue.js, vuex

I just want to test if `myAwesome` action is dispatched when my `App.vue` component is `created()`. Is this something you would test? I'm using Jasmine for these tests. Any help would be awesome!

App.js

```
describe('when app is created()', () => {
  it('should dispatch myAwesomeAction', (done) => {

    const actions = {
      myAwesomeAction() {
        console.log('myAwesomeAction')
        // commit()
      }
    }

    const state = {
      myAwesomeAction: false
    }

    const mutations = {
      LOAD_SUCCESS(state) {
        state.myAwesomeAction = true
      }
    }

    const options = {
      state,
      mutations,
      actions
    }

    const mockStore = new Vuex.Store(options)

    spyOn(mockStore, 'dispatch')

    const vm = new Vue({
      template: '<div><component></component></div>',
      store: mockStore,
      components: {
        'component': App
      }
    }).$mount()

    Vue.nextTick(() => {
      expect(mockStore.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalled()
      expect(mockStore.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith('myAwesomeAction')
      done()
    })
  })
})
```

Errors:

```
1) should dispatch myAwesomeAction
     App
     Expected spy dispatch to have been called.
webpack:///src/views/App/test/App.spec.js:49:6 <- index.js:50916:50
webpack:///~/vue/dist/vue.esm.js:505:15 <- index.js:3985:24
nextTickHandler@webpack:///~/vue/dist/vue.esm.js:454:0 <- index.js:3934:16
     Expected spy dispatch to have been called with [ 'loadOrganisation' ] but it was never called.
webpack:///src/views/App/test/App.spec.js:50:54 <- index.js:50918:54
webpack:///~/vue/dist/vue.esm.js:505:15 <- index.js:3985:24
nextTickHandler@webpack:///~/vue/dist/vue.esm.js:454:0 <- index.js:3934:16
```

Answer (score 2):

The thing is, you are trying to unit test a store from a component, so there's a little bit of a problem when you are mocking some elements and relying in true functionality in other elements. I'm no expert in vuex, I had a similar problem trying to spy on a store action and call a component's method (can't remember what the problem was, i remember i did waste half a day with it).

My suggestion: test component as unit, then test store module as unit, that means in your app component you can spy

```
spyOn(vm, 'myAwesomeAction');
Vue.nextTick(() => {
    expect(vm.myAwesomeAction).toHaveBeenCalled()
    done()
});
```

(that is, check if initializing your component, your method that calls the store action is called, in my example myawesomeaction will be a mapAction name in the methods object)

And then, you can unit test your store, and check that if you call myawesomeaction the mutation on that component will occur

check the test action helper here: https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/testing.html